# validate.js validating array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

I have a java script object that contains two array properties:

I'm using the [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/#validate-js) library.

For example:

```
var customer = {
   name: 'Ted',
   address: 'some address',
   friends: ['Michelle','Elon'],
   purchases: [{ qty:1, goods: 'eggs'}, { qty:2, goods: 'apples'}]
}
```

I want to validate the following:

1. That the array of friends contains only elements of type string.
2. That the array of purchases contains at least 1 purchase but max 5 purchases and that the qty is always numeric.

How can i do that with validate.js?

Comment: It will be released soon: https://github.com/ansman/validate.js/pull/184

Answer (score 17):

You could make a [custom validator](https://validatejs.org/#custom-validator), let's call it `array`:

```
import validate from 'validate.js/validate'
import isEmpty from 'lodash-es/isEmpty'

validate.validators.array = (arrayItems, itemConstraints) => {
  const arrayItemErrors = arrayItems.reduce((errors, item, index) => {
    const error = validate(item, itemConstraints)
    if (error) errors[index] = { error: error }
    return errors
  }, {})

  return isEmpty(arrayItemErrors) ? null : { errors: arrayItemErrors }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
const customerConstraints = {
  purchases: {
    array: {
      qty: {
        numericality: {
          onlyInteger: true,
          greaterThan: 0,
          lessThanOrEqualTo: 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const customerErrors = validate(customer, customerConstraints)
```

then in the render block when iterating over the `customer.purchases` array you can see if any purchase items have an error by checking `customerErrors.purchases.errors[index].error.qty`

Comment: Hi Good day, I am new to mongoose, I've been too many articles and forums regarding element(string) validation inside array but nothing works for me. I guess you may help me. As of now I have tags: [ {type: String, minLength: 2, maxLength:50, trim: true}] which is only min, maxLength is not working. Thank you

Comment: I think the custom validator should check whether the input is an array or not. It should also check array elements are of type 'object' or not. In case of Objects it should use 'validate', and in case of primitive types it should use 'validate.single'